# Add metadata to AngularJS resource object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Suppose I have a resource like the typical one from the AngularJS docs:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
```

Is it possible to store some metadata in the object that will survive another request? This is what I want to happen:

```
var bob = User.get({userId: '123'});
// {id: 123, name: 'Bob'}
bob.$foo = 'foo';
// {id: 123, name: 'Bob', $foo: 'foo'}
bob.$get();
// {id: 123, name: 'Bob', $foo: 'foo'}
```

Notice that the `$foo` field is still there after the call to `$get`.

I suspect that this isn't possible. In that case, where is a better place to store it?

Comment: No, it's not possible to put those directly in the resource instance. See: [angular-resource.js#L33](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ngResource/resource.js#L33), all properties are cleared before mixing the new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your own get function that retains the metadata:

```
User.prototype.getButKeepMetadata = function () {
  var foo = this.$foo;
  var self = this;
  this.$get(function () {
     self.$foo = foo;
  });
}
```

And instead of `bob.$get()`, do a `bob.getButKeepMetadata()`.

Comment: This is pretty cool. You could automatically copy over certain fields by some prefix (e.g. `$`).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking it's not possible as you stated it.  You could store the result and any updates in an angular constant. That would allow you to have a client side copy in any controller you inject it while still making http requests.

**Update with Constant Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/jonesmac82/D292w/6/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
'MyCtrlModule',
'myConstant'
]);

var testCtrl = angular.module('MyCtrlModule', []);
testCtrl.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', 'user', function ($scope, user) {
    $scope.returnedResource = {
        fullName: 'john doe',
        userId: 123
    };
    user.username = $scope.returnedResource.fullName;
    user.userId = $scope.returnedResource.userId;
}]);

testCtrl.controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', 'user', function ($scope, user) {
    $scope.newVariable = user.username;
}]);

var testCostant = angular.module('myConstant',[]);
testCostant.constant('user', {
    username: null,
    userId: null
});
```

Constants are a great way to share info between controllers and can be updated as new http request data comes in.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: What is an angular constant? Can you give an example? Currently I'm thinking the best way is to store the metadata and resource in some wrapper object, and pass the wrapper around instead of a direct reference to the resource.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I don't think this quite addresses the issue, because it assumes I'll only have one user (since it's a singleton). I guess one could store a map of users as a singleton instead, and store the metadata in the map - but then you would have to manually remove users from the map when they are no longer needed.